# Ant doesnt build Liferay Themes correctly (no '_diffs' applied)

Tags: tomcat, ant, liferay, hudson

I am using hudson to remotely checkout, build and deploy my Liferay 6.1.2 project to tomcat.
This worked fine until recently I added new themes. Now it seems all themes get built and deployed correctly but when I open up the website I mostly only see the parent themes without all the modification that was inside the "_diffs" folder.

If I build them on another computer the wars is generated as it should.

Developer mode is disabled.

Does someone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: and what say the build log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ant to build, take a look at files in the root of your plugins-sdk. You can override the settings in `build.properties` (don't change that file) in one of `build.${username}.properties` or `build.${hostname}.properties`

Determine what user hudson runs as and configure the file appropriately. Or just use the hostname and configure that one. Also, if you ever ran the build as a different user, make sure that hudson has write access to the files/directories that potentially are owned by another user